# Unable to de-serialize redis cache data in php

Tags: python, php, redis, azure-ad-msal

I have created python application and using redis cache to store azure session. It's storing in redis as some endoded format as below. Python is able to convert but when I am trying to read in PHP code it's not able to de-serialize because of encoded values. The data stored in the redis cache having prefix with some extra characters like below -

When I access the Key(mp-app-session) through command line:

```
\x80\x04\x95\xd4(\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\x94(\x8c\n_permanent\x94\x88\x8c\x15identity_context_data\x94}\x94(\x8c\x0e_authenticated\x94\x88\x8c\t_username\x94\x8c\x10
```

when I display using php redis client ( Key(mp-app-session))

```
 Array
(
    [0] => ���(}�(�
_permanent���identity_context_data�}�(�_authenticated���    _username��
```

Code used to display in UI using php

```
    $arList = $redis->mGet(['mp-app-session']);
 echo '<pre>';print_r($arList);die;
```

What format is that? and How to read or de-serialize the data stored in Redis Cache?

Comment: Your serialization and deserialization code, please.

Comment: My python application writes into Redis and I am reading in PHP code as updated above

Comment: include the relevant python code